# Php including files

Tags: php, apache, file, include

I wanted to know how files are included in php.

What I mean by that is that how the variables from the included files are imported and how the included file is able to use the variables from the main file.

I was creating a templating system and the problem was that I had an index file which included the other files such as config.php etc. But then depending on the page requested the index.php contained the template files too. But for some some reason I wasnt able to use the variables from the config file from in the template.php file

Comment: it's variable scope issue, not include. do not include inside of function if you want to access global variables

Comment: A good idea is to imagine the included script replacing the `include()` statement in place. Then it gets apparent how the variable scope failed you.

Comment: I believe it is also a matter of timing too.  If you try to use a variable before the file is included, you will receive an error.

Comment: Ahh, I've almost forgot another possible case, a funny one, when not a file but HTTP resource being included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is `vars.php`

```
<?php

$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';

?>
```

below is `test.php`

```
<?php

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A

include 'vars.php';

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

?>
```

simple one from http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

declaring `global variables`

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

Variable scope is inherited.

You can even return a value from an `include`d file! Otherwise you may mostly consider the function to be simple, text-based (lexical) insertion.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php for more information.

Comment: The documentation says, explicitly:

"When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope."